# calling .animate 2 times for the same element

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({'marginLeft': "+=100px",
    'height': "100px",
    'width': "100px",
  }, 3000).animate({'backgrounColor': "blue"},5000);
  })
})
```

Hi, I am working on jquery animation in which div element changes it`s size and position (this part lasts 3 seconds) and after it`s finished it changes it`s background color to blue (5 seconds). The first part is working ok but i have no idea how to deal with setting break before color change starts or calling .animate twice

Comment: if you want to change the background color after the first animation is complete, you can use the complete callback in animate

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#div').animate({'marginLeft': "+=100px",
                       'height': "100px",
                       'width': "100px"}, 3000, function() {
                                                 $('#div').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                                                   $("#div").animate({'backgrounColor': "blue"},5000)
            });
        });
```